# Proving the base of a gramian matrix with a defined form

Tags: linear-algebra

Be $V$ n-dimensional in a $ \mathbb R  $ vector space und be $q$ a nondegenerate quadratic form on $V$. To prove: It exists a base $B$ of $V$ in $ \mathbb R  $, in which the gramian matrix of $q$ is defined as

$\begin{bmatrix}1 &  &  &  &  & \\  & ... &  &  &  &  \\  &  & 1 &  &  & \\ & &  & -1 &  & \\ &  &  &  & .. & \\ & &  & & & -1\end{bmatrix}$

I don't know how to start proving this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use induction on $n$. 
The case $n=0$ is trivial. For $n>0$, there exists a vector $v$ such that $q(v)\neq0$, since the form is non-degenerate. After scaling $v$ by $1/\sqrt{|q(v)|}$ one will have obtained $q(v)\in\{-1,1\}$. Take this $v$ as first or last basis vector, depending on the sign of $q(v)$. Now $v^\perp$ is a a complementary hyperplane to $\langle v\rangle$, and the restriction of $q$ to$~v^\perp$ is easily seen to be non-degenerate. Induction applied to $v^\perp$ completes the basis.